# Drawing custom icon on form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls, gdi

I'm creating a custom control in C# winforms. I've added an ICON to the resource, this icon is then drawn onto the control using the code below:

```
using (Icon oIcon = Properties.Resources.DropDownCustom)
{
    Rectangle RectangleIcon = new Rectangle((DropDownRectangle.X + ((DropDownRectangle.Width / 2) - (oIcon.Width / 2))),
        (DropDownRectangle.Y + (((DropDownRectangle.Height / 2) - (oIcon.Height / 2)) + 1)),
        oIcon.Width,
        oIcon.Height);
    graphics.DrawIcon(oIcon, RectangleIcon);
}
```

This all works fine no problem, but then I decided to add an option to the control properties to allow the developer to load their own icon to use rather than use the one I've placed in the resource. I created a private Icon variable:

```
private Icon _DropDownCustom;
```

changed the "using" line in the above code to read:

```
using (Icon oIcon = _DropDownCustom)
```

and then added to the constructor the following line to set the default value to the one in the resources.

```
_DropDownCustom = Properties.Resources.DropDownCustom;
```

I've then added an Icon property so the developer can use thier own icon:

```
[Category("Appearance"), DisplayName("IconDropDown")]
public Icon IconDropDownCustom
{
    get { return _DropDownCustom; }
    set { _DropDownCustom = value; this.Invalidate(); }
}
```

All this seems to be working fine, except now, when I view the control on a form (in development mode) it paints the icon onto the control - great, but as soon as I select the form, or the control the Icon disappears, but other painting stays (ie grading background).

Does anyone know why it doesn't seem to repaint the icon?

Many thanks.

EDIT:
I've just removed the "`Using(){}`" part of the code and changed it to:

```
Icon oIcon = _DropDownCustom;
Rectangle RectangleIcon = new Rectangle((DropDownRectangle.X + ((DropDownRectangle.Width / 2) - (oIcon.Width / 2))),
    (DropDownRectangle.Y + (((DropDownRectangle.Height / 2) - (oIcon.Height / 2)) + 1)),
    oIcon.Width,
    oIcon.Height);
graphics.DrawIcon(oIcon, RectangleIcon);
```

This seems to work as expected so I'm guessing it's something to do with using and disposing - Still trying to understand the displosing part - could you please explain why this is happening? I'm guessing my "oIcon" is basically just referencing my custom Icon variable rather than "by value" (I'm from a VB background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "using" block around your Icon resource will signal to the GC that the memory at that location is no longer needed and it will clean it up. So, after the first time it gets drawn the Icon will no longer be valid (unless you load it and dispose it every time you draw it).

You should probably either:

- Handle the close event of the control and dispose of the resources there.
- Implement the [Disposable](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) pattern on your user control to clean up resources (like your Icon) when your control is no longer needed.